# What can't the human eye see far-UV, X-rays, and gamma rays?

Tags: vision, biophysics

This is as much of a physics question as it is a biochemistry question. But how does rhodopsin(and the retinal chromophore itself) respond to ionizing radiation? Photons whose wavelength is longer than 700nm do not have the energy to photoisomerize retinal. But for photos with wavelength shorter than 300nm for sure have more than enough energy to do so.